# Can't replace string with variable

Tags: python, regex, variables

I came up with the below which finds a string in a row and copies that row to a new file. I want to replace `Foo23` with something more dynamic (i.e. [0-9], etc.), but I cannot get this, or variables or regex, to work. It doesn't fail, but I also get no results. Help? Thanks.

```
with open('C:/path/to/file/input.csv') as f:
    with open('C:/path/to/file/output.csv', "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if "Foo23" in line:
                f1.write(line)
```

Comment: What is this dynamic thing you're trying to write? As the code stands, you're testing if the line has "Foo23" and then printing it if it's there. All other lines will be ignored.

Comment: @malan under regex, what I would like to search is for any line containing `r"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d"`

Comment: `...but I cannot get this, or variables or regex, to work.`  - please read [mcve].  Show us what you are trying to do that doesn't work - include an example input string(s).

Comment: @physlexic: You don't know what module and commands to use to search for `r"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d"` Try `import re` and then test `if re.search(r"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d", line):`

Comment: @malan sorry maybe I should have explained it better, but by `or regex` in my initial question, I meant that I did try `import re` etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to match lines whenever any three letters followed by two numbers are present, e.g. `foo12` and `bar54`. Use regex!

```
import re
pattern = r'([a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2})\b'
for line in f:
    if re.findall(pattern, line):
        f1.write(line)
```

This will match lines like `'some line foo12'` and `'another foo54 line'`, but not `'a third line foo'` or `'something bar123'`.

Breaking it down:

```
pattern = r'(                  # start capture group, not needed here, but nice if you want the actual match back
             [a-zA-Z]{3}       # any three letters in a row, any case
                        \d{2}  # any two digits
            )                  # end capture group
            \b                 # any word break (white space or end of line)
           '
```

If all you really need is to write all of the matches in the file to `f1`, you can use:

```
matches = re.findall(pattern, f.read())  # finds all matches in f
f1.write('\n'.join(matches))  # writes each match to a new line in f1
```

Comment: You don't need an f-string for this pattern.

Comment: `\w{3}` will match much more than just 3 letters

Comment: Why do you have the variable `my_string`, it isn't being used

Comment: @DillonDavis from a previous version of the answer that I changed. Removed it now, thanks.

Comment: @wwii the f-string was from a previous version of the answer that I edited. Removed now, thanks.

Comment: @Engineero thank you..! subsequently, if I wanted to write only the strings that match the `pattern` found by `re.search()` to the output, as opposed to the whole line, how would I do it? I have been searching, and am currently trying back-references, but no luck yet

Comment: @physlexic see my update. If you just want to grab all of the matches from the file, it's even easier!

Answer (score 1):

In essence, your question boils down to: "I want to determine whether the string matches pattern X, and if so, output it to the file". The best way to accomplish this is to use a reg-ex. In Python, the standard reg-ex library is `re`. So,

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2})', line)
```

Combining this with file IO operations, we have:

```
data = []
with open('C:/path/to/file/input.csv', 'r') as f:
     data = list(f)

data = [ x for x in data if re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2})\b', line) ]
with open('C:/path/to/file/output.csv', 'w') as f1:
    for line in data:
        f1.write(line)
```

Notice that I split up your file IO operations to reduce nesting. I also removed the filtering outside of your IO. In general, each portion of your code should do "one thing" for ease of testing and maintenance.